# How to sync a SharePoint Web Part with Teams?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, microsoft-teams

I have developed a SharePoint WebPart, this component has several properties that I can modify from SharePoint: width, height...

[image]

I have installed the same component in Teams and works fine but I don't know how can I change this properties in Teams.

Logically, I think that by changing the values in Sharepoint, they should automatically refresh in Teams but it's not like that.

On the other hand, If I try to click on the "Sync button with Teams", I don't why never works and throws an error.

https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/catalogApp/_api/web/tenantappcatalog/SyncSolutionToTeams --> Error 500

Somebody know how what can I do to sync this parameters?

[image: par]

Answer (score 0):

@vcima, Once you make changes, you need to build it, bundle it and create new package.
After package creation you need to upload this package. Check following steps to upload package
Go to SharePoint Admin >> Open Apps >> It will take you to App catalog >> Go to Distributed Apps - you will see all the packages

Just delete the existing appropriate package and upload the new package. After that from File menu, sync with Teams
for more detailed steps please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab#packaging-and-deploying-your-web-part-to-sharepoint).

Comment: Hi @Abhijit-MSFT, I had done this, but I always obtain the same result: Error 500 -- URL solicitada:https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/catalogApp/_api/web/tenantappcatalog/SyncSolutionToTeams
Método de la petición:POST
Dirección remota:xx.xx.xx.xx:443
Código de estado:
500
Versión:HTTP/2
Política de referencia:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload your webpart package in sharepoint app catalog, You can click on sync with teams button in catalog. Your webpart will be synced with teams and will be visible in teams as tab. However You can edit the webpart within sharepoint site itself but editing a webpart within teams tab is not possible.Please take a look at [Making the SPFx webpart available within Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab#making-the-web-part-available-in-microsoft-teams)